# How to get Order Independent Transparency in VR/Unity working?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, transparency, oculus

I'm using [This github project](https://github.com/candycat1992/OIT_Lab) to create order independent transparency in my projects. It's working fine with a normal camera [[no OIT](https://gfycat.com/CharmingCoordinatedAdmiralbutterfly)]  [[OIT](https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/HiddenThoroughIcelandicsheepdog)], but when I try to use it with a VR setup, it just doesn't render any object on the "transparent" layer that is using the above project. [[VR no OIT](https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/ShinyPettyLemur)]   [[VR no working with OIT](https://gfycat.com/gifs/detail/ColorfulSameBluemorphobutterfly)].

On top of just not rendering anything marked as transparent, the left and right cameras become offset in a way that they shouldn't, so you get a disorienting effect as if you're eyes are in the wrong place.

I'm using the Oculus SDK, but I don't think it's that. The same thing happens if I just use a camera that feeds to the Oculus headset.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fuzA4I67qC-8dX5Z4aMS0_1G9LgvEJVz/view?usp=sharing) is the Unity project, if you want to see for yourself.

Thank you

EDIT: I was also occassionally getting a weird effect where the spheres would render all black and remain centered on my left eye, and the rest of the scene was rendered upside down. The right eye would render everything not marked as transparent correctly. I believe I was using the single camera setting in the OVR camera rig when this happened, but I couldn't get it to produce the same error when I went back to record these errors.

Additionally I am using Unity 2018.2.0f2 and the Oculus SDK v1.30.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Order-Independent-Transparency in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52843254/order-independent-transparency-in-unity)

Comment: I don't think this is a direct duplicate - the rendering artifact (invisible vs wrong order) and environment is quite different. The other answer was not directly responded to. The indirect response (on another SO site) while correct and informative, is not very helpful without .

Comment: This seems not to be duplicate. With "a VR" setup you refer to using the project in VR mode, e.g. with your Oculus Rift headset, I assume?